Parsing with a space (sscanf or strtok)
For some context, my game runs in the terminal and is like a command line type game. At the moment to process commands is does a strcmp() for every single command which isn't really pretty nor efficient. Because of this, I decided I should redo it. I tried looking at other posts and didn't find anything useful. What I'm looking for is for it to save each section of the command.
For example:
    //let's just say command = "debug test"
    char part1;
    char part2;

    split via " "

    part1 = "debug"
    part2 = "test"

I tried to use sscanf() but it would just cut down the string. For example let's say I gave it the string "test".
It would output:
test -> est -> st //and so on

Your title mentions strtok. That is useful for this. Why are you not using it?

@EricPostpischil I tried it but it didn't really work well.

Then that is your problem, not this vague question. Review the search functions section of the C standard (C 2018 7.24.5). strtok, strcspn, and strchr could each be used to aid parsing a string into parts. Study their specifications (or find information about them in a textbook, primer, or tutorial) and write code using one of them. Then, if you have problems, ask a specific question with a [mre].

char part1; wants to be (at least) char *part1; Learning is up to you alone.
